# XML Schema Display Elements in Unordered pattern

Tags: java, c#, xml, xsd

I have a Schema XSD File that has the elements listed in the **Sequence**. The problem is that Sequence forces the XML file to list the elements in the **order**. Now, I want to use the **choice** tag. But according to the **xml specification, choice** allows only one of the elements contained in the  declaration to be present within the containing element. Also, I can't use **All tag** because I want the **occurrence more than once**. But, I want to 
display all the **A, B, C, D and E** in the **un-ordered pattern**. Any suggestions?

### Xml Schema File

```
<xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="A" />
        <xsd:element name="B" />
        <xsd:element name="C" />
        <xsd:element name="D" />
        <xsd:element name="E" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

### XML File (I want these elements to be in any order)

```
<a>a</a>
<b>b</b>
<c>c</c>
<d>d</d>
<e>e</e>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a list of examples that should and should not be valid.  Thanks.

Comment: Your edit only restated your prose and still fails to communicate what's not allowed.  For example, you're saying ABCDE or EDCBA are valid.  Fine.  What about ABC?  (Do they all have to be present?)  ABCDEEEE?  (May some repeat while adjacent?)  AEBECEDE?  (May they repeat while interleafed?)

Comment: (1)Occurrence: 0 [Zero] or Multiple Times  (2) Adjacency: Yes, it can be like this ABCDEEEE and (3) Repeat while interleafed : Yes, it can be AEBECEDE. My only concern is I don't want to force the elements in order and they can occur more than once. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XSD,

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="r">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element name="A" />
        <xsd:element name="B" />
        <xsd:element name="C" />
        <xsd:element name="D" />
        <xsd:element name="E" />
      </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

will validate elements `A` through `E` as children of `r` in any order and in any number of occurrences.

### Explanation

The occurrence constraints on the `xsd:choice` element allow the choice itself to be repeated the indicated number of times.  So, you can make a choice between the child elements zero times and get an empty content model for `r`.  For one time, you can choose any of the children.  For a second time, you can choose the same child you did the first time, or any other child.  As you can see, this continued operation allows any number of the children elements to appear in any order.

### Examples

All of the following XML documents would be valid against the above XSD:

- `<r></r>`
- `<r><A/><A/></r>`
- `<r><A/><A/><A/></r>`
- `<r><A/><B/><A/><C/><A/><D/><A/><E/><A/></r>`
- `<r><E/><D/><C/><B/><A/></r>`

Comment: I do have a doubt on this one. Choice allows only one element to be present in the containing element. In this case parent element "r" can have only one element to be present, isn't it so? <r> <a>a</a> or <b>b</b> or.... other elements </r>. And if we put all the elements [a,b,c,d,e] inside parent element "r", we are not following the XML Schema Specification. Please correct me if I'm wrong.